# Usage of Date/Time Configuration Options

Tags: php, datetime, configuration, ini

I have read the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php), but couldn't find any proper explanation regarding the usage of the following options in `php.ini` file:

```
Date/Time Configuration Options:
date.default_latitude
date.default_longitude
date.sunrise_zenith
date.sunset_zenith
```

Perhaps anyone can explain when would the settings above be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

date_sunrise() and date_sunset() are two php default function which are used to find out the sunrise and sunset time for a particular day, and it takes as input params the longitude and latitude values, please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sunrise.php

Like for example
date_sunrise(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, $lat, $long, $zenith, $offset)
you can use the default $lat and $long values

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that sunrise and sunset times could be calculated using PHP. Thanks!